# EditText expands of fscreen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm loading data straight from a remote database in to an edit box, the trouble is when there is alot of data it sends the text  off screen rather than start new line. I have put marginRight = size etc in edittext but still carries on? any help thx

Answer (score 1):

In xml file select the attribute `android:singleLine="false"` and also `android:maxLines="10"`, 10 is not compulsory can change according to you.